# Install with docker - can't access port

Tags: installation, docker

I put this question on the wordpress.org forum a few hours ago, but have just discovered this stackexchange sub and expect I'll get a better response from you fine folk.

---

I'm attempting to install wordpress with docker-toolbox using [this guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-the-official-docker-wordpress-image/).

I get to the stage where both the mysql and wordpress containers are running, with ports & filesystem mapped. But when I try to load a page it can't connect.

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554805/getting-wordpress-docker-to-run-on-local-host) suggests that wordpress is denying requests that aren't from localhost, but gives no clue as to how to reconfigure this.

Is that likely to be the problem? How can I proceed?

Here's what I see, from scratch:

```
$ docker run --name wordpressdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress -d mysql:latest

16e01fb1add7994ee7588f73a360019ac6c210bba17b7eecdcbe76a4bb8f0f13

$ docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password -d --name wordpress --link wordpressdb:mysql -p 127.0.0.2:8080:80 -v "$PWD/":/var/www/html wordpress

eaabc394834b18ab2ff2fcbfa8451f1e652910a177487858e706c18c1cba7d64

$ curl localhost:80

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

Comment: From the potential SO answer on that other question you will need to command line on the machine with the mysql connection and look for the response using netstat. That would be a good way to eliminate other variables.

Comment: Very unlikely that WordPress itself is refusing connections. More than likely this is a service or firewall issue.

Verify that your web server is actually running and, if a firewall is running, that port 80 is allowing traffic.

A 'Connection Refused' error isn't likely to give you any real information but you could try to use curl or wget with the verbose option to see if there is any additional information being returned.

Also check you web server logs to see if it's actually receiving/logging the connection.

Comment: I think you might have got your port mapping the wrong way around. You've mapped port 80 on the container to host ip address 127.0.0.2 and port 8080. you probably wanted `-p 80:80` (by default the wordpress container listens on port 80). I'm assuming this is the official wordpress image.